# Generalized Gårding's inequality's problem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Please somebody can help me with this problem?
I tried to solve it, but I couldn't do it, and I can not find nothing on the web.

---

Let $H$, $Q$, $V$ and $W$ Hilbert spaces such that $H\subseteq V$ and $Q\subseteq W$, both with compact injections. Let $a:H\times H\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $b:H\times Q\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ bounded bilinear forms and define
$$B:(H\times Q)\times(H\times Q)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
$$B((u,\lambda), (v,\mu))\ :=\ a(u,v) + b(v,\lambda) + b(u,\mu),\quad \forall\ (u,\lambda),(v,\mu)\in H\times Q.$$
Suppose that there is a bounded bilinear form $a_0:H\times V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\widetilde{a} := a + a_0$ is $H$-elliptic, i.e, there is $\alpha > 0$ such that
$$\widetilde{a}(v,v)\ \geq\ \alpha\|v\|_H^2,\quad \forall\ v\in H.$$
Also, suppose that there is a bounded bilinear form $b_0:V\times W\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and a constant $\beta >0$ such that $\widetilde{b} := b + b_0$ satisfies
$$\sup_{\mbox{$v\in H\atop v\neq 0$}}\frac{\widetilde{b}(v,\lambda)}{\|v\|_H}\ \geq\ \beta\|\lambda\|_Q,\quad \forall\ \lambda\in Q.$$
Show that $B$ satisfies the **Generalized Gårding's inequality**, i.e, show there is $\widetilde{\alpha} > 0$, a bounded bilinear form $K : (H\times Q)\times(V\times W)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $S:H\times Q\rightarrow H\times Q$ an isomorphism, such that
$$B\left((u,\lambda), S(u,\lambda)\right)\ \geq\ \widetilde{\alpha}\|(u,\lambda)\|^2_{H\times Q} - K((u,\lambda), S(u,\lambda)),\quad \forall\ (u,\lambda)\in H\times Q.$$

---

Thanks so much in advance